# Seg fault at the specified line: Hash table insert/search functions

Tags: c++, xcode, hashtable

I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I'm trying to insert words into a hash table and am using separate chaining. Here is my class Hash.h that has, within it, class `wordData` to store the word and `pageNumbers` the word appears on:

```
class Hash
{

  private:
    class wordData
    {
      public:
        string word;
        vector < int >pageNum;
        wordData *nextWord;

        // Initializing the next pointer to null in the constructor
          wordData()
        {
            nextWord = nullptr;
        }

        // Constructor that accepts a word and pointer to next word
        wordData(string word, wordData * nextWord)
        {
            this->word = word;
            this->nextWord = nextWord;
        }

        // Getting and setting the next linked word
        wordData *getNext()
        {
            return nextWord; //-------------------> BAD_ACCESS ERROR
        }

        void setNext(wordData * newInfo)
        {
            nextWord = newInfo;
        }

        // Setting info for the word node.
        void setInfo(string & w, int pNum)
        {
            this->word = w;
            this->pageNum.push_back(pNum);
        }

        // ******************* Gives a thread-bad access error************************
        string getWord()
        {
            return word;
        }

        void addPageNums(int x)
        {
            this->pageNum.push_back(x);
        }
    };

  private:
    // Head to point to the head node of the linked list for a particular word
    wordData ** head;
    int size;
    int *bucketSize;
    int totalElements;

  public:

    // Class hash function functions
    Hash();
    // Function to calculate bucket number based on string passed
    int hashFunction(string key);

    // search if word is present
    bool Search(string);

    // Insert word
    void Insert(string, int);

    int bucketNumberOfElements(int index);
};

#endif /* Hash_h */
```

After running the debugger I found the value of nextWord to be 0x00000000000 which I understand is not the same as nullptr but is due to a NULL assignment although I can't seem to figure out where and why. I haven't included the Hash.cpp file because I think there is an obvious pointer manipulation that I'm doing wrong in the .h file.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In your title you mention, *specified line*. Which line is it?

Comment: I would question why you're obviously using a vector in your code, so you have access to standard containers, but then you're trying to implement your own container. I would recommend that you replace this entire class with a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<int>>` or similar.

Comment: @lurker: The getWord() method: return word;

Comment: @DarkFalcon: need to implement our own hash table for the assignment.

Comment: `return word` itself is not going to fault. The fault is happening somewhere else in your code. Perhaps somewhere very near where you actually call `getWord()`.

Comment: @lurker: you're right, I got the initial fault taken care of but now it gives me the same error on the new line I point out in the code above.

Comment: My same comment applies: `return nextWord` itself is not going to fault. The fault is happening somewhere else in your code. Perhaps somewhere very near where you actually call `getNext()`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll continue trying. Thanks for all your help.